# How to re-design the button of "react-google-login"?

Tags: reactjs

How to re-design the button of "react-google-login"?
I want to change this:
[image]

To This:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Actually, found the answer by my own, All I had to do is:

```
<GoogleLogin
        clientId="client_id_goes_here"
        render={(renderProps) => (
          <button onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled}>
            This is my custom Google button
          </button>
        )}
        buttonText="Login"
        onSuccess={onSuccessGoogleSignIn}
        onFailure={onFailureGoogleSignIn}
        cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
      />
```

Comment: I am trying the same thing, with the new Google Auth process now, but it isn't working